# accept/decline submit buttons looping with php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, submit

I'm trying to allow a user to accept/decline requests for an event through submit buttons. Information is looped and displayed in a row (username, location, accept,decline).

Right now 2 users are being displayed; User 1 and User 2(current ones for testing). Anyway, I'm trying to get the correct userid to work with the correct username. Currently, regardless of which user I accept or decline, user 2 is displayed. I tried to set the value of the userid based on a hidden input but it's not working correctly.

Here is my code.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($userExplode)-1;$i++){
            $user = mysql_query("select userid,username from users where userid = ".$userExplode[$i]." ");
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($user);
            $userLoc = mysql_query("select userLocation from userinfo where userid = ".$userExplode[$i]." ");
            $location = mysql_fetch_array($userLoc);
            $locationExplode = explode("~",$location['userLocation']);

//the displayed output is working correctly so I know it's setting $user['userid'] properly 
            echo '<form method="post"><table><tr><td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $user['userid'] . '">' . $user['username'] . '</a></td>
                <td>' . $locationExplode[0] . ', ' . $locationExplode[1] . '</td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="userReq" value='.$user['userid'].'></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept Request" ></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline Request" ></td></tr>';   
            }
                echo '</table></form>';
        }
            if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
                echo $_POST['userReq']; //displays user 2 even if I click user 1
                    }
            if(isset($_POST['decline'])){
                echo $_POST['userReq']; //also displays user 2 even if i click user 1 
            }   
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with your code:

- You don't close the `for`'s in the loop
- there is no action on your form
- you're starting a new table for each loop

Replace the submit button's by anchors and add the parameters in there. Then you can style the anchor to look like a button.

```
<input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline Request" >
```

becomes

```
echo "<a href="yourfile.php?userid=".$user['userid'].">Decline request</a>";
```

Remove all the `<form>`s and load everything in 1 table.

**Result:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['action']) AND isset($_GET['userid'])){

    switch($_GET['action']){
        case "accept":
            // do whatever
        break;
        case "decline":
            // do whatever
        break;
        default:
            die('something wrong');
        break;

    }

}

echo '<table width="100%">';

for($i=0; $i <= count($userExplode); $i++){
  $q = "
        SELECT u.userid,u.username, userLocation
          FROM users u
    INNER JOIN userLocation ul ON u.userid = ul.userid 
         WHERE u.userid = ".$userExplode[$i]."
  ";
  $rs = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());      
  $user = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

  $locationExplode = explode("~",$user['userLocation']);

  //the displayed output is working correctly so I know it's setting $user['userid'] properly 
  echo '<tr><td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $user['userid'] . '">' . $user['username'] . '</a></td>'.
       '<td>' . $locationExplode[0] . ', ' . $locationExplode[1] . '</td>'.
       '<td><a href="yourfile.php?userid=' . $user['userid'] . '&action=accept">Accept Request</a></td>'.
       '<td><a href="yourfile.php?userid=' . $user['userid'] . '&action=decline">Decline Request</a></td></tr>';   

 }

echo '</table>';
```

I think this is only the tip of the iceberg.. How do you get `$userExplode` for example? It is very weird and illogical. I assume that you first run a query to get all the users and then loop with this for?

Comment: you should use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is it safe to use $_GET for something like this? I guess I'll just have to check again on the other page to only allow it if the creator of the event is the one accessing that page.

Comment: It is safe if you make it safe. Only someone who is admin should be allowed to make these requests.

Comment: What's the point of the case section at the top? I can see how that would apply to the other file that is selected from the link; is that what you intended?

Comment: No, it's just a safety catch. If you now make a (small) mistake in your HTML with the URL parameters, you might not know why your script is not working, but with this catch, you will not that the query string is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In your example it looks like you have some code issues.  Here it is cleaned up a little:

```
    for($i=0;$i<count($userExplode)-1;$i++) {
        $user = mysql_query("select userid,username from users where userid = ".$userExplode[$i]." LIMIT 1");
        $user = mysql_fetch_array($user);
        $userLoc = mysql_query("select userLocation from userinfo where userid = ".$userExplode[$i]." LIMIT 1");
        $location = mysql_fetch_array($userLoc);
        $locationExplode = explode("~",$location['userLocation']);
        echo '<form method="post" action=""><table><tr><td><a href="profile.php?userid=' . $user['userid'] . '">' . $user['username'] . '</a></td>
            <td>' . $locationExplode[0] . ', ' . $locationExplode[1] . '</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="userReq" value='.$user['userid'].'></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept Request" ></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="decline" value="Decline Request" ></td></tr>';   
        echo '</table></form>';

     }

     if(isset($_POST['accept'])){
            echo $_POST['userReq']; //displays user 2 even if I click user 1
     }

     if(isset($_POST['decline'])){
            echo $_POST['userReq']; //also displays user 2 even if i click user 1         
     }
```

Based on your code, the array that's being passed should be:

```
     $users = "1|2";
     $userExplode=explode("|",$users)  // or whatever your delimiter is
```

To test, do a `var_dump($userExplode);` prior to starting your loop to make sure you've exploded the entries going it.

A source dump of the original page would be helpful as well.  If you could post that then I could see how your code is rendering the html form.